# PHP > File_get_contents + json_decode doesn't work

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I've got problem with using `Json` from : http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=Herdyn , I need get some information about Live Stream.
My code :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=Herdyn');
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->{'name'};
?>
```

When i upload it on server : http://blx.patrikpapso.com/herdyn/ , no error, just blank page, don't know what to do...

Comment: You sure you have error reporting enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `var_dump($obj);` and you will see that there is no property "name". The JSON is an array that contains an object with such a property:

```
$firstObj = $obj[0];
echo $firstObj->name;
```

or even

```
echo $obj[0]->name;
```

There is supposed to be at least an E_NOTICE though.